# Making the texture on this fighter jet jet

Tags: materials, shaders

[image]

my current progress I want only the nodes for the material of the body and not the texture on it.

[image: saab gripen]

Note its a composite material , hope this helps you to answer my question.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? Please also add more details (like a closeup shot and your current progress) otherwise the question is impossible to answer :).

Comment: Jachym Michal , i have now edited my answer and posted my progress

Comment: Just to be clear, you _don't_ want the camo pattern?

Comment: Robin Betts NO SIR I WANT ONLY A PLAIN MATERIAL

Comment: @DEFENCE Hey :). What *exactly* are you not happy with regarding your current progress? Please be as specific as possible. Also how does your node-setup look right now? Perhaps a simple Principled BSDF shader with grey color and high roughness would be enough.

Comment: Jachym Michal , My texture looks mettalic while the 2nd one isnt , fighter jets are made up of composite , so it needs to be a bit less reflective and but at the same time it needs to be really smooth. i want something like a matte or plastic finish , node pics would be appreciated

Comment: Hey :). Then what's the problem? Use Principled BSDF with Base Color = grey,  Metallic = 0 (so it's NOT metallic) and Roughnes ~ 0,7 (so it's rough)

Comment: Jachym Michal Thats working . thanks